# Dvz shoutbox sound on/off switch with saving value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i want to make shoutbox sound when shout is arrived. I've got a script and i styled button but i cant make script working.
script for sound is:

```
dvz_shoutbox.callbacks['update'].push(function(){
if ($('#shoutbox .entry.new').length) {
    var audio = new Audio(rootpath + '/images/dvz_shoutbox.mp3');
    audio.volume = 0.2;
    audio.play();
}});
```

And it works,but i want to add on/of switch that will turn on and off this script, also i want to style it when it's on and off.
I got css look like this:

```
button.unmuted,button.muted {
vertical-align: middle;
padding: 0px 15px;
background: #060922;
line-height: 30px;
margin-top: -42px;
margin-left: 148px;
position: absolute;}
```

`button.unmuted:hover {color:#c0c3bf}
button.muted:hover {color:#c0c3bf;}
button.muted:before{font-family: FontAwesome;content: "\f026";}
button.unmuted:before{font-family: FontAwesome;content: "\f028";}`

Can anyone help me ??

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is only one `button` in your HTML, you need to attach a **click event handler** to that `button`. The handler will toggle the classes `muted` and `unmuted` whenever the `button` is clicked.

Then, in your callback that creates the audio, you can check to see if your `button` contains the class `muted`. If it does, then do not play the sound.

Altogether, your code would look like so:

```
dvz_shoutbox.callbacks['update'].push(function(){

    var $button = $("button");

    if ($button.length && $button.hasClass("unmuted")) { // checck if unmuted
        var audio = new Audio(rootpath + '/images/dvz_shoutbox.mp3');
        audio.volume = 0.2;
        audio.play();
    }
});

$("button").click(function() { // adds click handler

    var $this = $(this);

    $this.toggleClass("muted");
    $this.toggleClass("unmuted");
});
```

Note: in order for the code above to work, make sure your `button` starts out with class `unmuted` in your HTML.

Comment: I add this in <script> but is not working so i save it as .js file and upload but still nothing. Style of button is not changing.
Edit1: I found in code on site that "var = $("button");" and "var  = $(this);" but in script is: "var $button = $("button");" and "var $this = $(this);"